# Drupal 8, как отобразить материал и форму на одной странице без косяков?

Tags: drupal, drupal8, drupal7

У меня есть модуль, который:

1. Создаёт блок
2. В этот блок добавляется своя форма

Этот блок вывожу на странице, по определённому адресу (прописываю в модуле в routing путь) 
Указываю в routing  подключение _controller (в котором по этому же пути подключаю library с своими css и js )

Проблема: 
Хочу создать страницу, прописать этот же путь, что и в модуле. 
Что бы можно было добавить текст через админку перед формой, добавленной в модуле.

Текст и форма выводятся на экран, но отказываются подключаться CSS и JS из модуля на эту страницу.
Подскажите как сделать правильно. Спасибо